# C# implicit variable how would it be stored if not initialized

Tags: c#, data-structures

I get asked what happens/what data structure would C# implicit variable be stored if not initialized?
like var a; 
and we never use var after that

But I could not find the answer online or searching the documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables

So I think it is mean to be a trick question where as var has to be = to same thing for the complier to decide what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'var a;' isn't legal because it doesn't indicate a type, so the compiler will reject it.
If you declare 'int a' and use it without initializing then the compiler will give also you an error.

So the answer is "you can't get there from here".  Variables must given a type, explicitly or implied from the assigned value, and must have been given a value before being read.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up - your question was

> What happens/what data structure would C# **explicit** variable be stored if not initialized

However the documentation you're looking at is for **implicit** variables - which *have* to be initialized else the code won't compile.